# How to publish an android app only for tablets with a resolution of 1024x600?

Tags: android, air, resolution

I need to know how to target a particular screen resolution, I've created an app that is best viewed only on a display with a resolution of 1024x600. Anyone knows what attributes i need to have in the manifest file for this scenario?

Comment: I don't think you can get that specific from the manifest. If you're uploading your app to the market I think you can specifically choose which devices you want it to appear for though. That is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is to allow only xlarge screens.
In manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Although why would want to market your app to only 1 screen resolution? If you are hard coding pixel values, you are implementing incorrectly. Use dp, match_parent (fill_parent), and weights.